# Run function when cell changes in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I want to execute a script when a cell changes.  Lets say I have columns A-L, when L changes (which is updated by a lookup formula from another sheet) that it executes a script (which works already) but has to call values from column B, E & H to include within the executed script.

There could be upwards of 500 rows which will change/update on 1 minute intervals.  Generally, once it's changed once it wouldn't change again but the rows may not change in sequence.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include, I want to include that it would also be useful to post a date/times stamp into column M once the function has executed

Comment: Kindly include your code and your sample sheet.

Comment: It's not that easy to share unfortunately without going into a full explanation of the whole document.

The function is to post to twitter.  The values in the rows are name, club and time.

I think If I can work out how to get the value of the row that has been edited I can pass this into the function.  So If L6 changes it would then take the value of the cell M6 and use this as the twitter text.  M6 can be auto generated based on the content of the other cells on that row.

What I need to know is how to tell the function to use M6 instead of the cell that was updated which is L6

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no trigger that can run a script when a value in formula changes. The only trigger that can detect changes in a cell and get its location is onEdit(e) which is only triggered when a human manually changes a value in a spreadsheet. See [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).

Comment: What if I put a formula into a cell that monitored another cell for <>”” and then run a function that way, would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this myself.  Here’s the steps I followed:

- created a cell with the combination of the cells I wanted to tweet.
- created an if statement that once was satisfied as TRUE ran the function
- the TRUE value came when the cell with the time in it was no longer NULL